# Вывести на экран значение элементов с нечетными индексами (1, 3, 5, …) не используя оператор проверки условия

Tags: c, for

Помогите сделать прогу, я не знаю как сделать вывод непарные элементов.

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
int main() 
{ 
int i,n; 
float x, s=0; 
float A[200]; 
printf("Input quantity  elements of array  "); 
scanf("%d",&n); 
srand(time(NULL)); 
 for (i=0;i<n;i++) 
    { 
    x=(float)(rand()%9)/24; // дробова частина 
    A[i]= rand()%200+x; // випадкові числа від 0 дo 99 + дробова частина x 
} 
 for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("   %5.2f",A[i]);
}
printf("\n_________________________________\n"); 
 for (i=1;i<n;i++) 
    {printf("   %5.2f",A[i]); 
    s=s+A[i];} 
printf("\nsum = %5.2f",s); 
 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Написать цикл с 1 с шагом +2?

Comment: "Непарный" по-русски — чётный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, проблемы никакой нет - просто замените в последнем цикле `i++`, которое увеличивает `i` на единицу на каждой итерации, на `i += 2`, которое как раз будет увеличивать `i` на 2. Как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, n;
    float x, s = 0;
    float A[200];

    printf("Input quantity elements of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x = (float) (rand() % 9) / 24; // дробова частина
        A[i] = rand() % 200 + x; // випадкові числа від 0 дo 99 + дробова частина x
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("   %5.2f", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n_________________________________\n");

    for (i = 1; i < n; i += 2) {
        printf("   %5.2f", A[i]);
        s = s + A[i];
    }
    printf("\nsum = %5.2f", s);

    return 0;
}
```